# HTTP Post with raw data in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, post

When I make this curl call:

```
curl --request POST \
  '<url>' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer '<auth_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"raw":"<base64 encoded data>"}' \
  --compressed
```

The request works and I receive an `HTTP 200 code`.  I am not able to do this in `node.js`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What HTTP code and response you see when you are trying to send this request using Node? Or what error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'whatever.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/todos',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http request client like "axios"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios